# 'Many more' or 'Much more' in this case?

Tags: grammar

> ...a number of health benefits might be associated with this delicious treat. These include improving one's mood, reducing memory decline especially in older people, warding off cancer, and ______ more.

I put the answer as 'much', and the answer key says it's 'many'. Through some research, I found that 'many' is used in front of plural countable nouns and 'much' is used in front od uncountable nouns.

I put the answer as 'much' as the examples are uncountable - memory decline is uncountable; cancer is not a countable noun. Also, much gives the feeling of **A LOT** compared to 'many'.

Is the reason why the answer is 'many' as the sentence gives 'examples' which are countable plural nouns?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is because the text is about health benefits. The word "benefit" is countable. And the author lists them: improving one's mood, reducing memory decline, warding off cancer and MANY more [health benefits]